# Graphic glitch ttk widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, ttkwidgets

It all started from the fact that a normal `tk.Scale` was not feared correctly (I'm using a custom theme).
I then switched to `ttk.Scale` but it was not showing the value above the slider when I changed it.
I then discovered ttkwidget, which seems to work but with graphical glitches. Anyone have any ideas to fix?
Code: https://pastebin.com/bxgvsjSF
Screenshot: https://ibb.co/tLdjLrx
P.S. Furthermore, the the widgets that have problems are very slow to load widgets

EDIT: solution is in the comment of the best answer

Comment: Are we supposed to assume what `ttkwidgets` is? Is it from the `tkinter` library?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. [This is `ttkwidgets`](https://github.com/TkinterEP/ttkwidgets)

Comment: The problem was caused due to widget from `ttkwidgets` right?

Comment: This question is actually less effective here as the error was caused not due to standard `tkinter` widget. You should probably ask the same question over at [issues](https://github.com/TkinterEP/ttkwidgets/issues) so the developers cant directly get in touch with you.

Comment: You can try ttk.LabeledScale (it has a small bug fixed in the last python)

Comment: Please don't link to code on other sites. Take the time to embed a [mcve] directly in your question.

Comment: @hussic Both `ttk.LabeledScale` and `ttkthemes.TickScale` have graphical glitches, though the ones of `TickScale` are slighlty worse (I am using python 3.9.1).

Comment: I guess that the glitches with `TickScale` and `LabeledScale` are performances issues when moving the `Label`. If you don't want glitches, the easiest would be to use a static label next to the slider.

Comment: Here you can see the very small ufficial fix: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/6ad5fd14825fc6039a9684dfdc14f5d12b86e25f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to get rid of the glitches in `ttk.LabeledScale`. I think the issue is the redrawing of the whole `Label` widget so I used a `Canvas` instead. With a `Canvas`, when the text is moved, there is no need to redraw the background so the animation is smoother.

The code below is based on the source code of the `ttk.LabeledScale` (from Python 3.9.1, you can find it in [tkinter/ttk.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.1/Lib/tkinter/ttk.py)). But the widget is now based on a `Canvas` in which the scale and text are added with `create_window()` and `ćreate_text()`. I modified the `__init__()` and `_adjust()` methods and I added a `_on_theme_change()` method which is called when the theme changes to update the styling of the canvas and adjust the positions of the elements.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class LabeledScale(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, master=None, variable=None, from_=0, to=10, **kw):
        self._label_top = kw.pop('compound', 'top') == 'top'

        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master, **kw)
        self._variable = variable or tk.IntVar(master)
        self._variable.set(from_)
        self._last_valid = from_

        # use style to set the Canvas background color
        self._style = ttk.Style(self)
        self.configure(bg=self._style.lookup('Horizontal.TScale', 'background'))
        # create the scale
        self.scale = ttk.Scale(self, variable=self._variable, from_=from_, to=to)
        self.scale.bind('<<RangeChanged>>', self._adjust)

        # put scale in canvas
        self._scale = self.create_window(0, 0, window=self.scale, anchor='nw')
        # put label in canvas (the position will be updated later)
        self._label = self.create_text(0, 0, text=self._variable.get(),
                                       fill=self._style.lookup('TLabel', 'foreground'),
                                       anchor='s' if self._label_top else 'n')
        # adjust canvas height to fit the whole content
        bbox = self.bbox(self._label)
        self.configure(width=self.scale.winfo_reqwidth(),
                       height=self.scale.winfo_reqheight() + bbox[3] - bbox[1])
        # bindings and trace to update the label
        self.__tracecb = self._variable.trace_variable('w', self._adjust)
        self.bind('<Configure>', self._adjust)
        self.bind('<Map>', self._adjust)
        # update sizes, positions and appearances on theme change
        self.bind('<<ThemeChanged>>', self._on_theme_change)

    def destroy(self):
        """Destroy this widget and possibly its associated variable."""
        try:
            self._variable.trace_vdelete('w', self.__tracecb)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            del self._variable
        super().destroy()
        self.label = None
        self.scale = None

    def _on_theme_change(self, *args):
        """Update position and appearance on theme change."""
        def adjust_height():
            bbox = self.bbox(self._label)
            self.configure(height=self.scale.winfo_reqheight() + bbox[3] - bbox[1])

        self.configure(bg=self._style.lookup('Horizontal.TScale', 'background'))
        self.itemconfigure(self._label, fill=self._style.lookup('TLabel', 'foreground'))
        self._adjust()
        self.after_idle(adjust_height)

    def _adjust(self, *args):
        """Adjust the label position according to the scale."""
        def adjust_label():
            self.update_idletasks() # "force" scale redraw
            x, y = self.scale.coords()
            if self._label_top:
                y = 0
            else:
                y = self.scale.winfo_reqheight()
            # avoid that the label goes off the canvas
            bbox = self.bbox(self._label)
            x = min(max(x, 0), self.winfo_width() - (bbox[2] - bbox[0])/2)
            self.coords(self._label, x, y)  # move label
            self.configure(scrollregion=self.bbox('all'))
            self.yview_moveto(0)  # make sure everything is visible

        self.itemconfigure(self._scale, width=self.winfo_width())
        from_ = ttk._to_number(self.scale['from'])
        to = ttk._to_number(self.scale['to'])
        if to < from_:
            from_, to = to, from_
        newval = self._variable.get()
        if not from_ <= newval <= to:
            # value outside range, set value back to the last valid one
            self.value = self._last_valid
            return

        self._last_valid = newval
        self.itemconfigure(self._label, text=newval)
        self.after_idle(adjust_label)

    @property
    def value(self):
        """Return current scale value."""
        return self._variable.get()

    @value.setter
    def value(self, val):
        """Set new scale value."""
        self._variable.set(val)

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.theme_use('alt')

scale = LabeledScale(root, from_=0, to=100, compound='bottom')
scale.pack(expand=True, fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you but i had finally figured out how to create what i want. in  `ttkwidgets.Tickscale` i set the `digits=0` and now the label below is disappeared and the value that slides is an integer